# Authorization header malformed. [jwt_auth_bad_auth_header]

Tags: plugins

I installed the plugin `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` a month ago, and manage to get it work with my integration, it was working perfectly until they update this plugin, now I got this error and can’t figure out what is the problem.
I did try with my application obviously and also with postman, both returns the same error.

`Error: Authorization header malformed. [jwt_auth_bad_auth_header]`

In their webpage there's nothing related to the update.